# how to disable android 7.0 signature v2 to install a modified apk?

Tags: android, apk

i modified a apk with deleted some sound  & so files for slim the file size, and install successly in android 5.0, but it doesn't work on android 7.0, the phone will show "apk is broked" . so how to disable android 7.0 signature v2 to install a modified apk?

Comment: 1. Ask developer for the source 2. recompile app with own signature 3. install ...

Comment: That's kind of the point of the V2 signature scheme; once the APK has been signed it shouldn't be possible for anyone to modify the contents of the APK. If you make changes to an app then it' a different app and you'll have to re-sign it with a different keystore. In the unlikely event that someone would post a working exploit on StackOverflow it's obviously going to be seen by the developers at Google.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be and Android6.0 above permissions

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you referring to the runtime permission model introduced in Android 6.0? If so, I don't really understand what that has to do with the V2 signature verification.

Comment: I see you described in 5.0 above can be run at 7.0 but not, I think it may be related to the authority

Comment: The question is about trying to bypass Android's signature verification of a modified APK.